# How do you unit test a NodeJs Lambda function that writes/reads to dynamodb and is invoked via an AWS API Gateway endpoint?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I have a lambda function that is invoked by a get/post request to an API Gateway endpoint and then based on the request it reads/writes from/to a DynamoDB table.
How can I unit test the function?
I found this library called `lambda-tester` but it doesn't play well when dealing with Dynamo db.
I also tried the Amazon's `unit and load testing` blueprint, but am not a big fan because it writes the results to yet another dynamo db table and I would rather just test locally and see the output on the terminal.

Comment: Sounds like you know how to run Lambda functions locally, you just need a way to test or simulate DynamoDB without hitting the actual DynamoDB service on AWS. Have you considered running DynamoDB locally? http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/DynamoDBLocal.html Also, not sure what you mean about lambda-tester not "playing well with dynamodb". Did you encounter errors there? Or does it just not provide some feature you expected?

Comment: @MarkB When I ran a test, it failed because it seemed like it wasn't able to read from the database. I did consider running dynamo db locally, but then In code I have to specify an endpoint (i.e. localhost:8000) when creating a dynamo db table and then remove when I upload the code to lambda. Doesn't seem right. I might be missing something though, on how run/access dynamodb locally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually was able to use my non-local dev database after setting up AWS CLI, which required the necessary AWS credentials. Once you do that and set the region in the code, you can access your non-local dev database without a problem and test the code.

Answer (score 1):

We are working on a set of tools for just this. Take a look at this blog:

http://docs.bespoken.tools/en/latest/tutorials/tutorial_bst_emulator_nodejs

Our primary intention is to help Alexa development, but you can "talk" to any lambdas. Is your lambda an Alexa skill (and dynamo is for persistence)?

Comment: No it's simply a means to read/write to dynamo. How would unit testing a lambda work on your tool?

Comment: The tool proxies the incoming POST body into the lambda. It essentially exposes your lambda handler as an http endpoint. You can follow this tutorial http://docs.bespoken.tools/en/latest/tutorials/tutorial_lambda_nodejs until the "configure your skill" part.